# Nikon SB-600 remote operation nonsense

Tags: lighting, nikon-d7000

Okay, so I have a Nikon D7000 and 2 SB-600's. One of the SB-600's will only fire when controlled remotely via commander mode or via SU-800. (it no longer registers when hooked up to the camera, I'm thinking internal wire issue to the mounting foot), and the other functions as expected.

Now, I have an Orbis Ring Flash that I slip over the fully operational SB-600, and connect it via an SC-28 sync cable to the camera... I want the "on camera" (since it's connected via SC-28) SB-600 in the ring flash to trigger the SB-600 behind the subject. It this possible?

If I replaced the SB-600 on camera with a Yongnuo YN568EX II in master mode, would that fix anything?

Thanks in advance for your input all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an SB-600 cannot trigger another SB-600 in CLS.  The SB-600 is slave-only and has no commander capability, like the SU-800, and no SU-4 "dumb" optical slave mode that doesn't require a commander unit.

And I gather that the ring flash keeps you from using the D7000's pop-up as a CLS commander?

> If I replaced the SB-600 on camera with a Yongnuo YN568EX II in master mode, would 
>   that fix anything?

Unlikely, since, AFAIK, the YN-568EXII only comes in a Canon flavor and its master capabilities are Canon-only. To quote from [the Flash Havoc review of the YN-568EXII](http://flashhavoc.com/yongnuo-yn-568ex-ii-canon/):

> The new YN-568EX II is exactly the same as the current YN-568EX except for an added 
>   Master control for the Canon optic wireless system.

Like the YN-568EX, it can be used as a CLS *slave* which is where all the misleading marketing text is coming from.

Just my opinion, but maybe it's time to trade in the busted SB-600 for an SB-700.